# Raspberry pi cant listen to port 80 (express.js)

Tags: express

so I am using raspberry pi as web server and if I want to start express app there's an error:

```
events.js:291
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1293:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1358:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1444:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/malinapi/Documents/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/malinapi/Documents/app.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1337:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 80
}
```

Raspberry pi: 4, model b

Answer (score 0):

Any server listening on ports 1024 and below must initially be opened as root and not as an ordinary user. I'm guessing it is running as the user `malinapi`.

It is either that or you already have something running on port 80

Comment: I dont have anything running on port 80 and malinapi in raspberry pi imager is like administrator I think and if I want to login as pi with password raspberrypi or raspberry it says access denied

Comment: It must run under an id of `0`, the pi user does not.

Comment: what? can you explain? edit: oh it is

Comment: I do not believe that you are running it as the user `root`. Please edit the post with the full command line and the output of `id`.

Comment: full command line? like node app.js?

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: too long by 806 chars

Comment: events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1293:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1358:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1444:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/malinapi/Documents/node_modules/express/lib/applic                                                                                                                                                             ation.js:635:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/malinapi/Documents/app.js:9:5)

Comment: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js                                                                                                                                                             :60:12)

Comment: Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1337:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 80
}

Comment: bruh
node app.js

Comment: wait you mean app.js code?

Comment: nope I'm not young kid I just cant do two things in this same time

Comment: malinapi@malinapi:~/Documents $ node app.js

Comment: so how to run it as root? I am raspberry pi beginner not master

Comment: First, go find some basic guides, there are many. Second, try `sudo node app.js`.